# Is it appropriate to ask about a user's professional affiliation?

Tags: discussion

I found an answer on this site that was posted in response to one of my questions. I plan on writing and publishing a paper that mentions the result found by the poster (The result is just a small part of the paper, but the poster should still get the credit for that part of the result). I would like to be able to give full credit to the one who posted the answer, but to do that, I need to know the person's professional affiliation - either company or university.

Apparently, there is no way to send a personal message on this site. Is it appropriate to just simply ask in the forum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could leave a comment under the answer, saying that you plan to use the result in your paper, and inviting the author to suggest a form of attribution (they may or may not want to disclose it in a comment, but may be willing to email you).

There is a good chance that the user will not be excited about connecting their professional identity to their Stack Exchange account, in which case they will probably decline or ignore your request.  You can still cite the post following [Stack Exchange attribution guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: Thanks, @Normal. I was unaware of the attribution guidelines, which definitely gives me a way of proper attribution even if the user is not comfortable posting professional identity.